# Return rows with userId null or without based on group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have following table named: `DATE_PARAM`:

```
ID  FROM_VALUE      TO_VALUE                    PARAM_NAME      USER_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2016-01-01      2017-01-01 00:00:00.000     date            NULL
2   2016-02-01      2017-01-01 00:00:00.000     date            -1
3   2016-02-01      2018-02-01 00:00:00.000     anotherDate     NULL
4   2016-04-01      2018-02-01 00:00:00.000     anotherDate     3
```

This table list all available parameters. `PARAM_NAME` is name of parameter and it is unique per parameter. `USER_ID == NULL` means this is attribute defined by administrator. `USER_ID` == any number means that this parameter belongs to user.

What I would like to achieve for example for parameter: `userId=-1` - First I group those records by `PARAM_NAME`. Then in first priority I would like to get attribute which belongs to him (`USER_ID=-1`) but if there is no attribute which belong to him (within same `PARAM_NAME`) I would like to get provided by administrator `USER_ID=null`.

Expected result:

```
ID  FROM_VALUE      TO_VALUE                    PARAM_NAME      USER_ID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2   2016-02-01      2017-01-01 00:00:00.000     date            -1
3   2016-02-01      2018-02-01 00:00:00.000     anotherDate     NULL
```

I am not sure if it can be realized by query and even if yes if It will be good in performance. I tried do a self left outer join but still do not have expected result.

**EDIT - ANSWER**

```
select distinct
    isnull(users.from_value,admin.from_value)  from_, 
    isnull(users.to_value,admin.to_value)  to_,
    param_list.param_name  PARAM_NAME,
    users.user_id USER_ID
from
    (Select param_name from DATE_PARAM) param_list
left join 
    (select * from DATE_PARAM where user_Id = -1) users on users.param_name = param_list.param_name
left join 
    (select * from DATE_PARAM where user_id is null) admin on admin.param_name = param_list.param_name;
```

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE USER_ID = -1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE USER_ID IS NULL`

Comment: First of all, the table is not a list of Parameters, there are multiple rows in the table for both parameter `date` and parameter `anotherDate`. It looks like it might be a table of periods (date ranges) when a parameter was/will be tied to (associated with?) a specific user.  Define the schema better or more clearly please.

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY [PARAM_NAME]` clause to @MaciejLos comment and you should be fine

Comment: Please post your attempt to use a self-join so that we can help debug it.

Comment: @Charles: full use case: administrator defines list of attributes (criteria for search) which is available per attribute (PARAM_NAME). IF user will customize it it means he will create new record based on administrator one and he will fill userID. Now i would like to get all user attributes if present. If not i would like to get administrators ones.

Comment: @maciej: not at all. It will give me "date" with userID null and userId =-1 but i would like to have only userID=-1 if present

Comment: Check @BastianThiede comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select param_name from parameters
```

Above statement assumes you have a parameter table that is simply a list of all parameter.  This builds the list of all parameters for you to use as a base.  We are then going to left join it twice to this table, once for the user ID and once for the null rows.

```
...
from ( Select param_name from parameters) PARAM_LIST
left join (select * from tbl where user_Id = -1) users
    on users.param_name = param_list.param_name
left join (select * from tbl where user_id is null) admin
    on admin.param_name = param_list.param_name
```

This will now give you a row for every parameter and the user value and the admin value.  Now it's a matter of using isnull's in your select statement to find the right one.

```
select isnull(users.from_value,admin.from_value), 
       isnull(users.to_value,admin.to_value),
       param_list.param_name,
       isnull(users.user_id,'admin')
```

Put it all together

```
select isnull(users.from_value,admin.from_value), 
       isnull(users.to_value,admin.to_value),
       param_list.param_name,
       isnull(users.user_id,'admin')
from ( Select param_name from parameters) PARAM_LIST
left join (select * from tbl where user_Id = -1) users
    on users.param_name = param_list.param_name
left join (select * from tbl where user_id is null) admin
    on admin.param_name = param_list.param_name
```

edit... sqlserver is isnull not ifnull...I think

Comment: Could You please tell me what means user in Your case? Is it alias? Problem this i changed "tbl" and "parameters" to my table name: DATE_PARAM but its not compile under "user" and "admin".

Comment: honestly I shouldn't have used the word user as it's a reserved word.  User and Admin in this case are the subqueries alias's.    You will need to know the concept for subquerying.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Nice!! It works as expected!! I just edited 'admin' just to return users.user_id and did a distint on root query. Thank You very much!